How to style a specific nested tag from a parent element using Tailwind CSS?
I want to style an <a> tag inside a  using Tailwind CSS. I want to add the style via the parent <ul> tag. I tried [&>li>a], but it doesn't work as expected.
Here is my HTML structure:
<ul class="flex items-center [&>li>a]:hover:text-white">
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="/"> Route3 </a>
    </div>
    <a href="/"> Route2 </a>
    <span class="hero-chevron-right separator-icon"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

How can I achieve this styling correctly? I don't want to change any config or add new selectors.

"it doesn't work as expected". Can you explain what you expect?

i only have access to ul which is parent i want to add hover to  inside 
i want to know is it possible to select this tag with this method in tailwind?

I have no idea (I don't know Tailwind) what [&>li>a] is doing but it's not correct for what you want [&>li>div>a] would be right but I don't know if that's even possible.

I tried it before asking the question, but it didn't work as I expected. when we hover on one <a> all the <a> tags inside other s will change color
[&>li>*>a]:hover:text-[#ffcdcd]
I want only the <a> tag that is hovered over to change color


You need to move the hover: modifier to the front. The position of the modifier affects the final selector's effectiveness.
If you need to select all levels of <a>, in CSS you should select li a instead of li>a, which only selects direct child elements. But note that in Tailwind you need to use _ instead of spaces.



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<ul class="flex items-center hover:[&>li_a]:text-white">
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="/"> Route3 </a>
    </div>
    <a href="/"> Route2 </a>
    <span class="hero-chevron-right separator-icon"></span>
  </li>
</ul>



If you're sure that the child element of ul must be li, you can simplify the selector even further to: hover:[&_a]:text-white.

The way you've written it, the :hover applies to the ul. You want [&>li_a:hover]:text-white
<ul class="flex items-center [&>li_a:hover]:text-white">
  <li class="flex items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="/"> Route3 </a>
    </div>
    <a href="/"> Route2 </a>
    <span class="hero-chevron-right separator-icon"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

